# Adding javascript to the OnBlur property of an ASP.NET text box control

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Is there a way to specify some JavaScript to execute on the OnBlur event of an ASP.NET text box?  It seems to me like if I add any event handlers to the TextBox object they will just cause postbacks to the server isntead of doing what I want.  Basically, I just want to be able to have the textbox be rendered in this HTML:

```
<INPUT type="text" onblur="alert('1234')" />
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Could also go for:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" onblur="Javascript:alert('1234');" />
```

if you dont feel like setting it up in the codebehind.

Im guessing the reason why you end up with postbacks, must be because you have set AutoPostBack on the textbox to true. That makes the textbox postback when the client-side onchange event is triggered. Switch it to false, and it will act as a normal input-element.

Answer (score 11):

In your codebehind, add this:

```
myTextBox.Attributes.Add("onblur","alert('1234');");
```