# on blur function not working for input type date

Tags: jquery

I have a input type date like this

```
<input type="date" id="install_date" name="install_date" required="required" placeholder="Install Date" />
```

And I want to call a function

```
$("#install_date").blur(function() {
   // my code

});
```

but this is not working, please help me

Comment: have you give the id: install_date to that field?

Comment: from which control you wanna fire blur

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        install_date.Attributes.Add("onblur", "function_name()");           
    }
```

and in the script, add the function like,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function function_name() {
    //your code.
}
</script>
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: <input type="date" id="install_date" name="install_date" required="required" placeholder="Install Date" /> I want to fire blur from this control,please help

Comment: can u give some additional info,

Comment: $("#install_date").blur(function() { var hid = document.getElementById("spiffid").value;
 
 var edate=document.getElementById("install_date").value;
 alert(edate);
 
  var dataString = 'spiffId='+ hid+'&edate='+edate;
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
      url: "views/check_date.php",
      data: dataString,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data1) {
       
     var installdate  = data1.edate
     
       if(installdate<=edate)
       {
        
        alert("Please Enter Valid Install Date");
        $('#install_date').focus()
       }
           
          
   }  
  });
  
 });

Comment: i am writting this within $(document).ready(function(){ and then want to validate when user select wrong date, HTML is <input type="date" id="install_date" name="install_date" required="required" placeholder="Install Date" />

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384820/adding-javascript-to-the-onblur-property-of-an-asp-net-text-box-control